# How Do I Know If I'm On A LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

This is a really basic and dumb question. In my house we have a single modem/router, through which we all (three computers, TV, printer) connect to the internet.

My question is - does that mean we are on a LAN? If not, how do I create one?

The root of this question is that I want to play some games over a LAN with my child - so we need to be on a LAN. I've tried as if we were on a LAN, but it can't find the games we start up, so I'm wondering if we're not actually on one?

Comment: You'll want to check your firewall settings on both PCs, and security settings on the router, as these could prevent your traffic from going from one PC to another.
For example, most routers can be configured to separate each device from each other, giving them internet access, but no access to local resources.

Comment: Note that certain consoles or services may need specific ports to be forwarded.  You can find these by a simple Google search, then update the indicated ports to router and/or system firewall.

Answer (score 2):

> does that mean we are on a LAN?

Yes. `LAN` does mean *Local Area Network* and that's exactly what all of the computers behind your router are in. The router has many internal IPs - all of the computers in your home (the LAN) - and one external IP, your public IP.

There are three address ranges for use in [private IPv4 networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Private_addresses) (called LAN):

```
Addresses                     Number of addresses   Classful description
10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255                16777216   Single Class A.
172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255               1048576   Contiguous range of 16 Class B blocks.
192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255               65536   Contiguous range of 256 Class C blocks.
```

The translation between these two, the LAN and the internet, is done by your router, probably with [Network address translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) which takes care of managing connections by translating internal IPs to *one* external IP and vice versa.

> How Do I Know If I'm On A LAN

If you have several internal IPs that differ from your external IP, the set of internal IPs is called a LAN.
**or**
If your computer's IPv4 address is in one of these ranges, you're in a LAN.